# Server linux apache and css lost

Tags: html, css, apache

Hi all and sorry for my english...

I have this strange problem on a website built in html and css

On localhost works correctly...

When I upload the site on the server, this work for some second, then the page refresh without CSS style page!

I can't understand why

If open the source of page, before there is

```
<link type="text/css" href="styles/simple.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

After

```
<style></style>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: slow internet connection and large css file?

Comment: try to go to the css file directly, maybe you forgot to upload it...

Comment: Does it refresh automatically? That in itself is weird.

Comment: css file is little and internet connection is not slow...

the css exist... in fact the first time the page works correctly

If I come back on the page after 5/10 minutes the page works correctly... Then 10/15 seconds and css file lost...
I don't know if I can tell here the site to show you directly the problem...

Answer (score 0):

is it a self hosted site or you are using a provider? Or in other words, do you have access to the server configuration? Looks like there are some .htaccess rewrite rules if there are no instructions on your code to reload the page.
EDIT: I have seen that you get these errors on reload:

```
TypeError: $(...).PikaChoose is not a function;
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString' (2 times);
TypeError: $slider.after(...).cycle is not a function
```

These means that you have some js that is making troubles. This also means that the browser stops including files (like js plugins that are returning error on call). SO: **if you load css after this error you miss that css.**
My suggestion is to:

1. load all the css first
2. load all the js after
3. consolidate all the css since you have many rules that overwrite each other
4. disable some wierd plugins like mod_pagespeed since it looks like this is one that is causing the issue

Comment: I'm using a provider (aruba)... There is not an htaccess file
But the problem will be also if I reload page... Not only when autorefresh...
Seem that the page work for 10 seconds, then crash......
I'don't know... Very strange...

Comment: Is there any code on your page that reload it? Can you provide at least an url? I also use Aruba without any issue but take care you can edit htaccess

Comment: Ok. I have been looping through the site for almost 20 minutes and I don't see any issue. What I can suggest is to consolidate your css in one single file and to check using firebug or other development tools if there are conflicts between each file (I have seen many instructions repeated and so overwritten). What browser are you using?

Comment: What? You open the site, after some second refresh and works correctly??

Comment: Yes... also navigating through the site I have no issues! I wrote you using the form on your site btw, does it work?

Comment: I don't know why you looking correctly the site...
I'm using explorer, chrome, opera and firefox with same result...
And same problem in other localtion, not only my home...
Now with https://hide.me/en/proxy always same problem.........